# st_buffer multipoint with different distance

Tags: buffer, r-sf, multipoint

I have a `sfc_multipoint` object and want to use `st_buffer` but with different distances for every single point in the multipoint object. 
Is that possible?

The multipoint object are coordinates. 
[table = data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPUXD.png)

Every coordinate point (in the table in "lon" and "lat") should have a buffer with a different size. This buffer size is containt in the table in row "dist". 
The table is called data.

This is my code:

```
library(sf)
coords <- matrix(c(data$lon,data$lat), ncol = 2)
tt     <- st_multipoint(coords)
sfc    <- st_sfc(tt, crs = 4326) 
dt     <- st_sf(data.frame(geom = sfc))
web    <- st_transform(dt, crs = 3857)
geom   <- st_geometry(web)
buf    <- st_buffer(geom, dist = data$dist)
```

But it uses just the first dist of (0.100).
This is the result. Just really small buffers.
[small buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Ehv.png)

For visualization see this picture. It´s just an example to show that the buffer should get bigger. [example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9UW2.png)

Answer (score 4):

I think that he problem here is in how you are "creating" the points dataset.

Replicating your code with dummy data, doing this:

```
library(sf)
data   <- data.frame(lat = c(0,1,2,3), lon = c(0,1,2,3), dist = c(0.1,0.2,0.3, 0.4))
coords <- matrix(c(data$lon,data$lat), ncol = 2)
tt     <- st_multipoint(coords)
```

does not give you multiple points, but a single MULTIPOINT feature:

```
tt
#> MULTIPOINT (0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3)
```

Therefore, only a single buffer distance can be "passed" to it and you get:

```
plot(sf::st_buffer(tt, data$dist))
```

[image]

To solve the problem, you need probably to build the point dataset differently. For example, using:

```
tt <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("lon", "lat"))
```

gives you:

```
tt
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>  dist    geometry
#> 1  0.1 POINT (0 0)
#> 2  0.2 POINT (1 1)
#> 3  0.3 POINT (2 2)
#> 4  0.4 POINT (3 3)
```

You see that `tt` is now a simple feature collection made of 4 points, on which buffering with multiple distances will indeed work:

```
plot(sf::st_buffer(tt, data$dist))
```

[image]

HTH!